# I have to store Primary key of 1st table to 2nd table in MVC entity framework DB first. foreign key in MVC

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I have tried `Tempdata`, globally declared and session using MVC with entity framework 6 db first approach

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    //i have to pass or store cusid to paymentModel

    public int Cusid { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter username")]
    public string Cusname { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Phone")]
    public string Cusphone { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Address")]
    public string Cusaddress { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "select gender")]
    public Nullable<int> Gid { get; set; }
    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter UID number")]
    public string Cusaadhar { get; set; }


}


    public class PaymentModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="select Brand")]
    public Nullable<int> Brandid { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Model")]
    public string Model { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Product")]
    public string Product { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter IMEI number")]
    public string Imei { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Amount")]
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Discount")]
    public string Discount { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="select date")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Paymentdate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Mid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Cusid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Empid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CusMid { get; set; }

}
```

This is my controller..

```
       public ActionResult CustomerSave(CustomerModel CusModel)
    {
          db_mobilestoreEntities2 ent = new db_mobilestoreEntities2();
          tbl_Customer cus = new tbl_Customer();

            cus.Cusname = CusModel.Cusname;
            cus.Cusphone = CusModel.Cusphone;
            cus.Cusaddress = CusModel.Cusaddress;
            cus.Gid = CusModel.Gid;
             cus.Cusaadhar = CusModel.Cusaadhar;

            ent.tbl_Customer.Add(cus);
            ent.SaveChanges();
```

//This latestid stored latestcusid i have to store this latestid to another table or another action.

```
        int latestid = cus.Cusid;
        TempData["cusid"] = latestid;

        return RedirectToAction("PaySave");
    }

        public ActionResult PaySave(PaymentModel Pmodel)
     {
       db_mobilestoreEntities2 ent = new db_mobilestoreEntities2();

       tbl_Payment pay = new tbl_Payment();
        pay.Brandid = Pmodel.Brandid;
        pay.Model = Pmodel.Model;
        pay.Product = Pmodel.Product;
        pay.Imei = Pmodel.Imei;
        pay.Amount = Pmodel.Amount;
        pay.Discount = Pmodel.Discount;
        pay.Paymentdate = DateTime.Now;
        pay.Cusid=??
        pay.CusMid = Pmodel.CusMid;
        pay.Mid = Pmodel.Mid;

        ent.tbl_Payment.Add(pay);
        ent.SaveChanges();
        int latestid = pay.Id;
        return RedirectToAction("Details");
    }
```

T have two tables.

> 1st is tbl_customer
>
> 2nd is tbl_paysave

I have to store `customerid`(primary key) to `tbl_paysave`(foreignkey i.e Cusid) after submitting 1st page  redirected to 2ndpage i.e Paysave

Answer (score 0):

You can send the value of parameter as shown below

To get the id of inserted master or header

```
int headerId = 0;
_db.ProductMasters.Add(objProdmst);
_db.SaveChanges();
headerId = objProdmst.HeaderId;
```

Now in your redirect try with

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "SavePayDetails", new { iHeaderId : headerId})
```

In this way you can do further action i.e., `Save` or `Update`.